# How to implement mysql record locking in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, locking, yii2

I want to implement record locking functionality in my Yii2 application.

If one user opens update link/record (Ex.`http://localhost/myproject/backend/web/user/update/1`) then another user cannot able to access thislink and user will get an `ALERT` message saying "*This record already opened by another user*". So the record/page should lock for another user. (Same like MS Excel locking)

Once first user finishes and leaves from that record/page then it should unlock and another user can read/update that data.

So how can I use mysql database locking mechanism here in Yii2 active records or is there any other way to implement this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

It's called Optimistic Locking and described in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#optimistic-locks). Here is an example of implementation:

```
// ------ view code -------

use yii\helpers\Html;

// ...other input fields
echo Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'version');


// ------ controller code -------

use yii\db\StaleObjectException;

public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    try {
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    } catch (StaleObjectException $e) {
        // logic to resolve the conflict
    }
}
```

Comment: I've did exactly whatever mentioned in official docs but its not working for me.

Comment: Its not going in `catch` block

Comment: Yii version must be 2.0.16. Is there any way for older version than that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add column *locked_by_user* to your table and when someone is requested *update* action you check *locked_by_user* column if it is set or not. If not, set it to the user_id who is request *update* action first. Also you need to be concerned about reseting *locks*. And consider cases when user just can close the browser window and then record will be locked until he makes any action like *save record* or *cancel editing*.

Comment: I thought about this approach. But what if two update requests were submitted 10ms apart? The first request hasn't updated the flag on the row yet, while the second request checks for it already. How do you overcome this scenario?